# How to search empty alternation with tcsh

Tags: shell, tcsh

I want to search some empty alternation with ls but nothing is working.
I have a list of files: `foo.txt` `foouubar.txt` `fooubbar.txt` `fooubar_1.txt` `foounix.txt`

I want to have only `foo.txt` and `foouubar.txt`

I tried:

```
ls foo\(*ubar\|\(\)\).txt
```

but the result is empty. Is there a mistake in my command line?

I am in tcsh

Comment: @GaborFarkas If you edit a post, please don't just add a tag, while you're at it, also look at the formatting, casing and superfluous spaces before punctuation.

Comment: @Anthon Sorry, I just took a glance at the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works with `tcsh`. I'd use a brace expansion operator, `{..}`, like so:

```
$ echo foo{,uubar}.txt
foo.txt foouubar.txt
```

This works by making a set of sub-strings that the string "foo" is alternatively added to. In this case we're using `{,...}` which means the first sub-string tried is nothing. The second sub-string is "uubar".

#### References

- [33.2. Filename Wildcards in a Nutshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch33_02.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you use `ls` with a pipe, the files are output a-line-at-a-time, allowing you to use `grep` and other filters; hence the following will work independently of the shell used (but will generate files on separate lines).

```
ls | egrep "foo(uubar|)\.txt"
```

If you want the columns back:

```
ls | egrep "foo(uubar|)\.txt" | column
```